# Python requests inside a Django view hangs out and needs timeout

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests, timeout

I'm seeking help for this rather strange behaviour.
I have a Django view that gets called after a button click in a Django template

```
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def create_key(request, slug):

    #some unrelated code

    try:
        r = requests.post(
            some_url,
            data={
                #some_data
            },
            auth=(client_id, client_secret),
            timeout=(req_to, res_to)
        )
        if r.status_code == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except ReadTimeout as to:
        # handle exception
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        # handle exception
        return False

    #some unrelated code
```

that basically calls an API endpoint to create a key.
Now the  request with Postman works fine, taking out that  python snippet and running it alone also works, but when put inside this Django view it hangs until reaches response timeout.

Does anybody has any idea or pointer on where  the problem might be?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: i've found similar problems but these while they share with me the same structure, the problem was somewhere else

[Why Python requests library failing to get response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38979817/why-python-requests-library-failing-to-get-response)

[LiveServerTestCase hangs at python-requests post call in django view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690718/liveservertestcase-hangs-at-python-requests-post-call-in-django-view)

Comment: Does the view work fine when called with Postman(with the requests code inside the View)?

Comment: @invinciblycool thank you for the reply. Yes, it does work perfectly.

Comment: And just to be sure, I hope you are not calling your own API from your server?

Comment: @invinciblycool no, it's an API on a totally different server